# Piwik Email Reports link is missing

Tags: report, reporting, matomo

I am trying to manage some Piwik reports that are going out on a scheduled basis. This help page mentions a "Email Reports" link that is supposed to be in my left menu. But the link is not visible in the Admin view.

https://piwik.org/docs/email-reports/

I can see the link in my personal view but not in the Administration view. I'm not sure who created the reports and I need to edit/fix/kill them.

What would cause the link to not display?  How can I turn the link back on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is intended. The reports aren't a feature of a website in piwik, but an user account. So every user is able to add, modify and delete his own email reports in his personal settings.

If you want to find out which user account has added the report you can check the `report` (or `piwik_report`) table in MySQL. There should be a column named `login` which shows the owner of the report.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, I've seen the reports link under my account. But the docs (in the link ) indicated otherwise, hence my confusion.
The author of the "bad" reports is no longer with our team. So I guess I will attempt to migrate the reports over to a new "owner."

Comment: Hi, I have contacted the piwik team and they have improved the help page.  I hope it is more clear now.